Separate/split a string into number groups and no-number groups
The following code could recognize a single number. but how to revise it such that it can split abc23.46de789f into {23.46 789} and  {abc de f} ?
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\xloop#1{%
   \ifx\relax#1\else
      \ifnum 2<1#1 #1 is number \par
         \else #1 is not number \par\fi
      \expandafter\xloop
   \fi
}

\xloop abc23.4de56f\relax 

\end{document}



@Mico thank you for editing.

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up a Lua function called split_num_nonum, which makes use of Lua's powerful string.gsub function to extract two separate substrings. If the numeric or non-numeric components of the input argument are empty, split_num_nonum returns empty substrings.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}

function split_num_nonum ( s )
   numstring   = s:gsub ( "[^%d%.]" , " " )
   nonumstring = s:gsub ( "[%d%.]"  , " " ) 
   tex.sprint ( numstring .. "/ " .. nonumstring )
end

\end{luacode}
\newcommand\SplitNumNonum[1]{%
  \luadirect{ split_num_nonum ( "#1" ) }}

\begin{document}
\SplitNumNonum{1abc23.456de789fg}

\SplitNumNonum{123.456789}

\SplitNumNonum{abcdefg}

\SplitNumNonum{}
\end{document}

